# Using "\" as a relation operator

Tags: f#, operators

Is there a way to use "\" as an infixed relation operator? Something like:

```
let \ y x = if x % y = 0 then true else false
```

Comment: As an aside, there's no need for that if. `if x % y = 0 then true else false` is the same as just `x % y = 0`.

Comment: Yea, I know expr = expr will return a bool... Just typed the rest out of habit I guess.

Comment: That's a terrible habit. ;-]

Comment: My bad! It won't happen again. Honest :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.** According to [Operator Overloading (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204.aspx):

> Allowed operator characters are !, %, &, *, +, -, ., /, <, =, >, ?, @, ^, |, and ~. The ~ character has the special meaning of making an operator unary, and is not part of the operator character sequence.